# Succinct expression for "an offer you can't refuse"

Tags: expressions

Supposing someone is currently employed and just isn't a fit on the team and management offers him a generous severance if he resigns immediately, otherwise if he refuses to resign immediately it is highly likely, though not totally guaranteed, that he would be fired for poor performance shortly afterwards.

I had thought of this scenario as a Hobson's Choice: one can either take the severance or not, however Hobson's Choice doesn't include the almost-certain negative consequence of not taking the severance; it implies that not taking the offer leaves one in their original state.

As a kind-of Game Theory payout matrix (for 1 actor) I suppose it could be expressed as:

Hobson's Choice:

```
Option A: +10 // Take it
Option B:   0 // Leave it
```

Dilemma:

```
Option A: -10 // Bad option 1
Option B: -10 // Bad option 2
```

This question

```
Option A: +10 // Severance
Option B: -10 // Be fired
```

Comment: Succinct or not, the situation might be described as "giving [the person] the chance to make a graceful exit."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a **no-brainer**?

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-brainer):

> no-brainer ‎(plural no-brainers)
>
> (informal) An easy or obvious conclusion, decision, solution, task, etc.; something requiring little or no thought.
>
> If the newer version performs as well for half the cost, the decision is a no-brainer.

You can see that their example sentence uses almost identical reasoning to that expressed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more along the lines of

```
Option A: +5   //severance 

Option B: -10  //fired
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider "**inescapable** offer/proposal".

> Definition : impossible to avoid, ignore or deny.
>
> Example: *And, most importantly, they need to accept this inescapable
>   reality: we need to talk*.